# How to set line height in Clutter.Text using Pango

Tags: gtk, gnome, clutter, pango

I want to have a [Clutter.Text](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Text) displaying text with double line spacing using [Gtk.Pango](http://valadoc.org/#!api=pango/Pango.FontDescription).

> note : in css, we would use `line-height: 200%` I think.

I tried this code and it didn't work:

```
var text_actor  = new Clutter.Text.with_text ("Roboto 10", "Long long text") ;
text_actor.width= SIDE_PANE_WIDTH ;
text_actor.get_layout ().set_spacing (2*Pango.SCALE) ;
```

Apparently, `Clutter.Text` keeps a cached version of the [Pango.Layout](http://valadoc.org/#!api=pango/Pango.Layout)

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way working around this by using CoglPango directly:

```
var t = new Clutter.Actor ();
t.set_size (300, 300);

// add some more text to see it
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, ...";

var layout = t.create_pango_layout (text);
layout.set_width (200);
layout.set_spacing (24 * Pango.SCALE);

t.paint.connect (() => {
    Cogl.pango_render_layout (layout, 0, 0,
                              Cogl.Color.from_4ub(0, 0, 0, 255), 0);
});
```

**edit** this is indeed the solution. Based on this, here's the code that I used:

```
            actor  = new Text () ; 
            actor.width= SIDE_PANE_WIDTH ;

            var text = "Some long text<b>Bold</b>" ; 
            var pango_layout = bio_actor.create_pango_layout ("");
            pango_layout.set_markup (text, text.length) ;
            pango_layout.set_spacing (2 * Pango.SCALE);
            pango_layout.set_font_description (Pango.FontDescription.from_string ("Roboto 10")) ;
            pango_layout.set_width (SIDE_PANE_WIDTH * Pango.SCALE);
            bio_actor.paint.connect (() => {
                    Cogl.pango_render_layout (pango_layout, 0, 0, Cogl.Color.from_4ub(255, 255, 255, 255), 0);
            });
            int width;
            int height ;
            pango_layout.get_size (out width, out height) ;
            actor.height = height / Pango.SCALE;
```

Comment: That's actually pretty terrible, and you're destroying all chances of the Text actor to cache the PangoLayout and avoid re-measuring text all the time, thus slowing down everything.

Comment: @ebassi how is what I proposed any different to what you propose at the end apart from the layouting in allocate/get_preferred*? Is there a different (better) function to paint the layout?

Comment: If you override the "paint" implementation and use your own layout, all the sizing will be incorrect; the clipping to avoid text painting outside of the actor's size is based on the allocated size, which you just trample. You're also overriding paint without preventing the original handler to run, which means you're painting your layout and then the actor will paint its layout on top, which only works because you're using an empty Text actor. I outlined the proper solution(s) below.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `ClutterText` caches the `PangoLayout` instance to avoid having to re-measure text every time it has to retrieve the preferred size. It actually caches the latest three instances of `PangoLayout`, because of the width-for-height/height-for-width geometry requests, but that's just an implementation detail.

Changing properties on the `PangoLayout` instance of `ClutterText` is also not going to result in updates to the `ClutterText`: you'd have to call `clutter_actor_queue_redraw()` afterwards, as the `PangoLayout` sits at a lower level than the actor in the scene graph.

In general, the `ClutterText` actor does not allow you to tweak the `PangoLayout` it creates; it's expected that the actor is in charge of creating an modifying the layout, and attempts at overriding that will result in either poor performance or undefined behaviour.

If you want to introduce a line spacing property then you'll have to file a bug against [ClutterText](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=clutter&component=ClutterText) — though that would mean that you'd have to wait until September for the next stable release of Clutter.

If you don't need all that `ClutterText` does, and you just want to display text, you could subclass `ClutterActor` and use `clutter_actor_create_pango_layout()` to create a `PangoLayout` that you can measure inside the overridden `get_preferred_width()`, `get_preferred_height()`, and `allocate()` virtual functions, and paint inside the overridden `paint()` virtual function.